# Como pintar una variable de un controllador en un blade Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

Estoy intentando pintar una variable $portatiles que en su interior hay una consulta sql:

```
public function create()
{
  //obtener mediante una consulta el numero de portatiles libres
  $builder1 = Inventario::orderBy('id');

  $builder1->select('inventario.*')
    ->join('equipos', 'inventario.idEquipo', '=', 'equipos.id')
    ->join('tipos', 'equipos.tipo', '=', 'tipos.id')
    ->where('tipos.tipo', '=', 'Portatil')
    ->where('inventario.estado', '=', 'Libre')
    ->count();

  $portatiles = $builder1->get();

  $reserva = new Reservas();

  $equipos = Equipos::all();
  $users = User::all();
  $inventario = Inventario::all();
  $tipos = Tipos::all();
  return view(
    'reservas.create',
    compact(
      'reserva', 
      'equipos',
      'users',
      'inventario',
      'tipos',
      'portatiles'
    )
  );
}
```

Todo esto está en la función crear de mi controlador, no se como poder pintar el resultado del interior de la variable en un campo option de un select.(esto en `create.blade.php`)

Las rutas funcionan perfectamente, por eso no hay problema, el único problema es el de poder pintar la variable en el option.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#additional-attributes

Answer (score 0):

en tu vista create deberias porder comprobar si recibes tus variables
de esta manera ej:  {{ $tipos }}

entonces si quisieras cargar tu select con los usuarios que estas enviando a la vista

Acá te doy un ejemplo con laravel collective en donde para la vista de crear productos, lleno un select (dropdown) con proveedores

##### Controllador de productos

```
public function create()
    {
        $product = new Product();
        $categories= Category::pluck('name','id');
        $providers= Provider::pluck('name','id');
        return view('product.create', compact('product',    'categories','providers'));
    }
```

##### Acá en el select dentro del form

```
<div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('provider_id') }}
        {{ Form::select('provider_id', $providers, $product->provider_id, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('provider_id') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'placeholder' => 'Provider Id']) }}
        {!! $errors->first('provider_id', '<div class="alert alert-danger" class="invalid-feedback">:message</div>') !!}
    </div>
```

Espero te sirva de ejemplo